# Unable to run maven tasks through MavenCli (maven-embedder)

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-embedder

I am using Maven embedder 3.3.3 in my program to run maven goals programmatically and I get the following error every time I run the `MavenCli.doMain` method:

> `-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory` system property is not set. Check `$M2_HOME` environment variable and `mvn` script match.

Comment: Well, did you set `-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory` to the project base?

Comment: I am able to run Maven commands on my system. I have never got this error

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since [Maven 3.3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29780763/1743880), there is a new system property called `maven.multiModuleProjectDirectory`. It is set by default to the root of the project (project base directory) by the [`mvn` (or `mvn.bat`)](https://github.com/apache/maven/blob/maven-3.3.9/apache-maven/src/bin/mvn#L243) script (so that is why you never experienced such an error before).

Therefore, when running Maven through `maven-embedder`, you also need to set this system property (see [source code](https://github.com/apache/maven/blob/maven-3.3.9/maven-embedder/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/cli/MavenCli.java#L330-L337) where the check is made). It needs to be set to the project root.

To set this system property, you can adjust your call to `doMain` and add

```
"-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=" + projectRoot
```

to the given arguments. An example would be

```
int result = cli.doMain(new String[] { "-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=" + projectRoot, "install" }, "/path/to/project", System.out, System.err);
```

Alternatively, you can call:

```
System.setProperty("maven.multiModuleProjectDirectory", projectRoot);
```

before invoking `MavenCli.doMain` method, where `projectRoot` points to root of the project you are building.

Comment: The `doMain` option does not work for Maven Embedder 3.5.2 as the check is made before the arguments are parsed for properties.

Answer (score 2):

Setting the system property in code, before invoking the CLI, worked for me on Maven 3.9. (As Mirvnillith observed, just adding it to the `doMain` arguments was not enough.) For example:

```
        MavenCli cli = new MavenCli();
        System.setProperty("maven.multiModuleProjectDirectory", new File(projectDir).getAbsolutePath());
        int status = cli.doMain(
                new String[]{"clean", "verify"},
                projectDir,
                new PrintStream(testOut),
                new PrintStream(testErr));
```

I also had to add `maven-compat` as a dependency, or I got past the first error and hit failures related to `RepositorySystem`.