# maven multiModuleProjectDirectory dependency

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, multi-module

I have added ${maven.multiModuleProjectDirectory} in my pom to mention the project as multimodule and show the path.
In my pom, it shows unresolved dependency. As it is an unresolved dependency, it is not breaking the build.

My questions are :

1. Is this safe to use this structure inside pom?
2. What can I do to resolve the dependency?

[pom file screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrvGK.png)

Comment: Hard to say from the picture, but if my guess is right, you are using IntelliJ.

As of now there is an open bug for this: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-190202?_ga=2.85220953.193816217.1636377121-1527866683.1636377121

See this discussion also, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29778262/what-is-maven-multimoduleprojectdirectory-used-for

Answer (score 0):

No, no, no! This is a private property and not meant to be managed or read by the user at all. You should rather describe the problem you have.